# Spring ouath2Authserver oauth/token returns internal server Error for grant client_credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-admin

Im trying to implement Authorisation server with password and client_credentials grant

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {



    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore jwtTokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    private TokenEnhancer jwtTokenEnhancer;

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer jwtTokenEnhancer(){
        return new JWTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(jwtTokenEnhancer(), jwtAccessTokenConverter));

        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder jcsb = clients.jdbc(dataSource);
        jcsb.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }
}
```

web config file

```
Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Allow eureka client to be accessed without authentication
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*/")//
                .antMatchers("/eureka/**")//
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**"); // Request type options should be allowed.
    }


}


@Configuration
public class JwtTokenConfig {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("dev");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

}
```

i have configured client details to pick up from database -

[image]

When i try to get access token based on password grant im able to get the access token

[image]
but when i try to get access token based on grnat_type client credentials - im getting internal server error .

Please help to check on what is wrong with my implementation.

enter image description here[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your class `OAuthConfiguration`, check client configuration present in `configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)` method. It appears that the JDBC client details service is not able to find any client details.

```
JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService = new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
jdbcClientDetailsService.listClientDetails(); // This probably would be empty.
```

If so, configure JDBC client details service something like this:

```
clients.jdbc(dataSource).withClient(CLIEN_ID)
           .secret(encoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
           .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials")
           .scopes("read", "write")
           .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).and().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Issue .

```
public class JWTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer{

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
        info.put("user-info", "user additional information...");
    //    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    //    info.put("isAdmin", user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);
        return accessToken;
    }
```

The commented line was causing the issue as there was no user in case of client_credentials